# Drag down formula in Excel changing upon file reopening

Tags: excel, batch-file, ms-office

So I wrote two batch files to store time and date. One is clock in the other is clock out

This is the batch file code for each batch file.

```
echo %date% %time% >> time_in.txt


echo %date% %time% >> time_out.txt
```

I have set up excel to update the spread sheet with the most current text files upon opening, it looks like this.

[image: Excel SpreadSheet]

As you can see the formula is off by one for the most updated times. All of the other times are still correct but the newest seems to take the values from the row below it. If I re-drag from the top formula down it fixes the problem, but only for that current session.

[image: Fixed Spread Sheet]

When I repeat the process for a new time and reopen excel to read the updated text files it produces the same problem. Does anyone know what this could be caused by?

Thanks

Comment: it may depend on how your code is working to copy down the cell.  posting a snippet of you code would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the help Ed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Data range properties, I changed the option for "If the number of rows in the data range change upon reset: **Overwrite exisiting cells with the new data, clear unused cells**

Also I checked the box **Fill down formulas in columns adjacent to data**

[image: My Solution]